# How to pass NSManagedObjectContext via Interface Builder's XIBs

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, xib, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a simple iOS application with one UIViewController beneath a UINavigationController. The UIViewController has an IBOutlet for an NSManagedObjectContext.

The AppDelegate has an IBOutlet for the nav controller - but not the view controller. The view controller is automatically instantiated ala the XIB process (as a child of the nav controller).

With this setup, how does one cleanly assign or pass the app delegate's NSManagedObjectContext to the view controller's IBOutlet property. There is a nav controller in the way :) and the app delegate doesn't have a direct property for the UIViewController.

It is a weird problem in that, I want to link a property from one XIB component to another component's property. Most of the XIB work I've done takes a property and points it to an object in the XIB which in turn - gets instantiated ala the normal process but in this case, the context is being created correctly in the app delegate, I just want to pass it on to the view controller when it instantiates it.

Comment: I think it is also worth considering an app that has 9 view controllers - used at different times - all of which need access to a managed context. In some cases, view-A and view-C need the context but view-B does not. A naive approach that simply passes it to every view controller as they are instantiated seems messy. Does that mean view-A creates view-B with a context (even though view-B doesn't need it) so that view-B can create view-C and pass it along? I find that makes my dumb view controllers too smart and the app inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass it, just grab it from the app delegate as required:

```
#import "MyAppDleegate.h"

NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [(MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: This is one approach (and a very practical one indeed) but to a certain extent, it hardcodes the context into the views themselves. I like that it inverts the setup but as a singleton, it violates the principle of "Dependency Injection". For instance, it would be hard to unit test this particular view controller in isolation since it would keep reaching out to the UIApplication and AppDelegate for resources that it needs. The ideal solution would "supply" the context to the view controller at runtime, the trick is in wiring it up ala IB.

Comment: True - in some apps where there are multiple threads accessing managed objects I've used a category on NSManagedObjectContext which creates mocs as required, using the thread name as an identifier - they are then stored stored in a dictionary with the thread's name as key. Obviously you have to name all threads and assert if you get a request from an unnamed thread. This is about the last thing that bugs me about using IB, I love the way XCode 4 makes the connections now but having to discover tricks to do stuff like passing in a moc is infuriating.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's docs recommend that you pass references to your managed object context to the classes the require them instead of referencing it from your app delegate.

Here's what the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` looks like in one of my Core Data projects.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    LocationsViewController *lvc = (LocationsViewController *)self.navigationController.topViewController;
    lvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    assert(lvc.managedObjectContext != nil);
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

You'll see that I also start with a UINavigationController with a single root view controller.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately, I don't have a reference to the main view controller in my app delegate - just the navigation controller.

Comment: But you have set up your main view controller in Interface Builder as the root view controller of your navigation controller. Just ask the navigation controller to return it's top view controller. Setup a public property on your view controller for an NSManagedObjectContext. Use `self.managedObjectContext` from the AppDelegate to set the `managedObjectContext` property on the view controller.

Comment: Yep, I could do that - but was looking for a way to do it in Interface Builder's XIB. I have 9 other view controllers that aren't on the nav stack that also need the managed object context and I'd like to apply it to those as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not been able to find away to wire this up in IB either. I just know there has to be a reason that Apple recommends passing along references.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but the problem you're wrestling with seems to be entirely of your own creation. You say that your app delegate has an outlet for the navigation controller, but not for the nav controller's root view controller, because you've set up your nib such that the view controller is created when the nib is loaded. There's nothing wrong with that, but there's also no reason that the app delegate shouldn't have an outlet for that controller. Indeed, the entire reason for outlets is to get references to things that are loaded from a nib.

Add an outlet to your app delegate for your root view controller, and connect it. The app delegate can then give the controller a reference to the managed object context.

With respect to your question about multiple view controllers, I wonder what sort of real-world app might have view controller (A), which needs data, load another view controller (B) which doesn't need any data, followed by a third (C) which again needs data? A realistic example might help, if you have one.

Remember that you don't have to pass the entire managed object context to each successive view controller. You can instead pass just the part of the model that the controller will need to do its work by passing a managed object.